# Calculate Kv for an OCXO (Tuning Law)

Tags: oscillator

I would like to calculate Kv value for an oscillator with the following datasheet :

https://dl6gl.de/media/files/ocxo-cti-osc5a2b02-datasheet.pdf

I have this formula to calculate it :

[image]

Found here https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/snaa106c/snaa106c.pdf

But I am not sure how to apply it to the data inside the sheet or if is missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like 0-4 V will get you -2 ppm to 2 ppm (min to max).  At 10 MHz 2 ppm is 20 hz, so 40 Hz/4 V is 10 Hz/V or 1E-5 MHz/V.

But according to the datasheet there's significant variation in the gain, and it could be as low as half the above number.

Comment: I concluded the same as 10 Hz / V  using linear slope